# Socket.io mime mismatch error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Here is app.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import http from 'http';
import event from 'events';
import io from 'socket.io';
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from 'passport';
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local';
import multer from 'multer';
import fs from 'fs';
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';
import postRoutes from './server/routes/posts.routes';
import commentRoutes from './server/routes/comments.routes';
import authRoutes from './server/routes/auth.routes';
import userRoutes from './server/routes/users.routes';
import {passportConfig} from './server/config/passport.config';
import {socketFunction} from './server/config/socket.io.config';
import path from 'path';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog');

const sanitizer = require('sanitize-html');
const app = express();

const server = http.Server(app);
const socket = io(server);
const localEvent = event.EventEmitter;
const myEvent = new localEvent();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

  next();
 });


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({
  secret: "some secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))

passportConfig(app);

app.use(postRoutes);
app.use(commentRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))


const port = 6655;

['/admin/', '/admin/:var', '/admin/edit/:var'].forEach(function(url){
  app.get(url, (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client', '/dashboard', '/index.html'));
  })
})

const blogRoutes = ['/', '/articles', '/articles/:url', '/contact'];

blogRoutes.forEach(el=>{
  app.get(el, (req, res)=>{
    if(el === '/articles/:url'){
      socketFunction(socket, req.params.url, myEvent)
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client', '/blog', '/blog.html')); 
  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, ()=>{
  console.log(`Express server listening on port ${process.env.PORT} and IP ${process.env.IP}`);
});
```

Here is my `socket.io.config` file

```
function socketFunction(io, url, event){
    const blog = io.of(`/articles/${url}`)
    const admin = io.of('/admin/home')
    blog.on('connection', (fromBlog)=>{
        console.log("Connection made on blog");
        fromBlog.on('comment', (msg)=>{
            event.emit('comment-posted', {
                msg: msg.message
            })
        })
    })
    admin.on('connection', (toAdmin)=>{
        console.log("Connection made on admin");        
        event.on('comment-posted', (msg)=>{
            toAdmin.emit('blog-comment', {
                msg: msg.message
            })
        })
    })
}

export {socketFunction}
```

and here are my two html files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="blog">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/blog" target="_blank">
    <title>Ayush Bahuguna | Web Developer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/blog/dist/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/blog/dist/js/vendor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/blog/dist/js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cms">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/admin">
    <title>Blog Admin | Ayush Bahuguna</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <root></root>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/dashboard/dist/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="/dashboard/dist/js/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="/angular-ui-tinymce/dist/tinymce.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="/dashboard/dist/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am receiving `The resource from “http://localhost:6655/socket.io/socket.io.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`

I checked the network tab, and the type on the `socket.io.js` file is set to text/html. I don't know why is this issue occurring, I don't have any catch all routes.

I tried to find a way around, by using the `socket.io.js` available in the `client` folder of the socket.io, but turns out that socket.io is not looking for that file and is explicitly looking for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @lix I have that in the html files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
const server = http.Server(app);
const socket = io(server);
...
app.listen(...);
```

You should either call listen on `server`...

```
server.listen(...);
```

...or let Express create an HTTP server for you (which is what `app.listen()` does, and it's also the reason why it's not working: when it creates a new server, that server doesn't have `socket.io` attached to it):

```
const server = app.listen(...);
const socket = io(server);
```

The `text/html` response that you got is probably because of a 404 response.